# Using std::string in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, stdstring, qstring

I have a STL codebase that need to be shared between a QtQuick 2.0 application (the graphical interface) and a purely STL application (the server). The interface can derive its classes from the shared STL codebase, so it can have `Q_PROPERTY`s, signals, slots, etc. but the shared data structures need to remain STL-only.

I'd like to avoid data duplication (`std::string` -> `QString`, etc.) so I tried to use `std::string` directly within the `Q_PROPERTY` system. Using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::string)` and `qRegisterMetaType<std::string>();` and declaring properties like:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString stldata READ stldata WRITE setSTLData NOTIFY stldataChanged)
```

makes my code compile, but QML still doesn't like `std::string`s.

Writing a text field with:

```
Text
{
 text: myserviceinterface.stldata
}
```

produces a warning saying `Unable to assign std::string to QString`, while appending an existing QML string:

```
Text
{
 text: "text: " + myserviceinterface.stldata
}
```

makes the `Text` control display a weird `QVariant(std::string)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid you can't use `std::string` directly within QML, you have to convert to `QString` first.

In general, you can only export two kinds of C++ types to QML: QObject-derived classes and some build-in value types, see [this documentation page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html). So using a `QString` as the type of a Q_PROPERTY only works because it has special built-in support in the QML engine. There is no way to add support for more of these *value types* like `std::string` (*).

Using `qRegisterMetaType` also doesn't help: It merely registers `std::string` as a meta type, which among others means it can be stored in a `QVariant`. It is (mostly) not relevant for QML integration.

So have your getter return a `QString`:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(QString stldata READ stldata WRITE setSTLData NOTIFY stldataChanged)
    QString stldata() const {
        return QString::fromStdString(myStlString);
    }
```

(*) Actually there is a way to add support for new value types, but that is private API in QML that needs to work directly with the underlying Javascript engine. The QtQuick module uses that private API to add support for e.g. the `QMatrix4x4` value type.

Comment: You're right, I gave up. Having a `QString` copy of an already available `std::string` is not the ideal solution however. This means more memory drained from an already constrained mobile device, more computation when updating both the strings and so on.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention another `QString` copy of the `std::string` as member variable, I just imagined it. Well, I suppose that I can just convert it every time that the interface needs to display the variable.